# How to get star coordinates for a given time

Tags: bugs, curated-data, astronomy, entity

**Fixed in 10.3.1**

---

In the documentation of [`StarData`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/StarData.html), there is an example that shows how to get the altitude of Sirius at a given time (in the [horizontal coordinate system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horizontal_coordinate_system)).

However, when I try to run the example code

```
StarData["Sirius", 
 EntityProperty["Star", 
  "Altitude", {"Date" -> DateObject[{2014, 4, 9, 22, 0, 0}]}]]
```

the result is

> ```
> Missing["NotAvailable"]
> ```

Additionally, if I run

```
StarData["Sirius", EntityProperty["Star", #]] & /@ {"Altitude", 
  "Azimuth"}
StarData["Sirius", 
   EntityProperty["Star", #, {"Date" -> Now}]] & /@ {"Altitude", 
  "Azimuth"}
```

I get the correct output for the first command and

> ```
> {Missing["NotAvailable"], Missing["NotAvailable"]}
> ```

for the second, which is very strange. Is this a bug with the `EntityProperty` function?

Comment: It appears there was a server-side change that's causing this to fail when it shouldn't.  I've notified the wolfram developers about this issue, and hopefully it will be fixed soon.

Comment: The astronomical curated data functions seem to be working normally with the current versions. Can somebody else confirm this?

Comment: @J.M. I can confirm it works in 10.4.0. Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: This works in 10.3.1, too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This bug appears to be fixed as early as of version 10.3.1.